# Set BackgroundColor of iText Document

Tags: java, itext7

I just cannot figure out how to change the background color of my Document. I did the same for other LayoutElements but it will not work in this case. How would you go about this?

```java
Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc, PageSize.A2);
doc.setBackgroundColor(backgroundgrey);
```

Comment: Are you asking in the context of itext 5 or itext 7? The tag [tag:itext] by itself is used mostly for itext 5 and earlier (add [tag:itext7] otherwise) but your code looks like itext 7.

Comment: You are right. I use iText 7. Thanks for the clarification.